# How to insert a variable like "n" into sqlite table using python sqlite3

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, parameter-passing

**My code is:**

```
import sqlite3 

def connectDB(n=-1,s=" ",d=" "): #n:  0-->copy \\1-->delete \\2-->rename \\3-->cut
    conn=sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    #print "Connected !"

    if n==-1:                   #if no Args -->give last record
        conn.execute("SELECT LAST(OPERATORCODE,FIRSTARG,SECONDARG) FROM TaskHis;")

    else:
        conn.execute('''INSERT INTO TaskHis (OPERATORCODE,FIRSTARG,SECONDARG)
        VALUES (n,s,d)''');
        conn.close()

    return True
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `LAST(...)` operator is not supported in sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

Use *parameters*:

```
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO TaskHis (OPERATORCODE,FIRSTARG,SECONDARG)
    VALUES (?,?,?)''',(n,s,d));
```

Read https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html for more information
and examples.